# Why does lsort remove '\' from the list elements?

Tags: tcl

lsort removes '\' from the list elements

```
set a [regsub -all {\d+} [list temp25 temp36] {\d+}]
puts $a
>>temp\d+ temp\d+
puts [lsort -u $a]
>>tempd+
```

I know the workaround to get desire result. **This question is more about asking whether this behavior is expected?** According to my understanding, **lsort** should not change the elements at any cost.

Answer (score 1):

> This question is more about asking whether this behavior is expected?

Yes. `regsub` operates and produces a string, while `lsort` works on a Tcl list. If you submit an arbitrary string to a list operation, then it might not get interpreted as expected. So, therefore, if you want to have a string (maybe superficially looking like a list) treated also as one, then you have to turn it into one explicitly using `split.`

Watch:

```
% set a {temp\d+ temp\d+}
temp\d+ temp\d+
% split $a
{temp\d+} {temp\d+}
% lsort -u [split $a]
{temp\d+}
```

If not properly sanitized, then characters special to Tcl like backslash or brackets will be processed as such. This is like:

```
% set _ temp\d+
tempd+
% # versus
% set _ {temp\d+}
temp\d+
```

Comment: Using split actually highlight the issue but doesn't justify it: Since lsort embeds the split functionality, there's no reason to behave differently than the "split" command. Otherwise, it should consider the full string as a single list element.

Comment: "Since lsort embeds the split functionality": This is not correct, no list operation (`lsearch`, `lsort`, name it) does an implict `split`, I am afraid.

Comment: ... the simple reason being that this would otherwise create a cascade of re-encoded lists of lists (i.e., their string reps): `[split [split $a]] ne [split $a]`. One has to be explicit about this.

Comment: I don't think its correct. If a list contains elements with a space, it fails . `set a {{temp\d+ temp\d+} {temp\d+ temp\d+}}
puts $a
puts [split $a]
puts [lsort -u [split $a]]`

Comment: If the list element doesn't have space, it doesn't enclosed by curly brackets. So for the elements without space, lsort removing '\' and for elements with space, lsort retaining '\'. `set a [regsub -all {\d+} [list [list temp2] [list temp3] [list temp25 temp3] [list temp36 temp4]] {\d+}];
puts $a;
puts [lsort -u  $a]`

Comment: @Drektz, what is the actual format of your input (the result of `regsub`)? The value of `a` in your comments is a different matter than in your OP. Different in the sense, they don't compare. `split` w/o split chars argument will explode a string based on whitespaces ... hence, the difference you see.

Comment: `split` is not to be used unconditionally, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, A. Richard meant that *split* and *lsort* might have the same behavior as for *a* string being passed as an argument. But they don't:

```
set a "{temp\\d+ temp\\d+} {temp\\d+ temp\\d+} temp\\d+ temp\\d+"
puts [split $a]
puts [lsort $a]
```

... and probably should not, as *split* gets a string, while *lsort* gets a list as input. If *lsort* gets a string, it converts the string into a list firstly, making the appropriate substitutions. Hence the issue ("\d" doesn't exist, so only "d" remains of it).

I.e., *lsort* performs firstly:

```
list {*}$a
```

and then sorts the result.